# Processing - Return type for method is missing

Tags: java, processing

Hopefully I formatted the code in the right way. This is my first time on stackoverflow. I just started coding and I have a question related to Proccesing (Java). The code below give me the following error: "Return type for method is missing"

```js
dayOfWeek(6);

void dayOfWeek(int x) {
  switch(x){
    case 1: print("Monday"); break;
    case 2: print("Tuesday"); break;
    case 3: print("Wednesday"); break;
    default: print("error"); break;
  }
}
```

As soon as I place the function call within the setup or draw function of Processing, my code works. See below:

```js
void setup(){
  dayOfWeek(1);
}

void dayOfWeek(int x) {
  switch(x){
    case 1: print("Monday"); break;
    case 2: print("Tuesday"); break;
    case 3: print("Wednesday"); break;
    default: print("error"); break;
  }
}
```

Does anybody know why my first example won't work and gives the error message?

Thanks in advance!

Mick.

Comment: You can*t put **expressions** just anywhere in your class. They should go into **into** methods. Or something like `class A { X value = someMethodCall(); ` works.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are very welcome. And for the record: you dont need all that "run code snippet" formatting. Just indent your source code with 4 chars, and you are done. Anything else is overkill (at least here)